# Variable Worksheet Name

Tags: vba, worksheet

I have a macro programme to do some operations like Vlookup, deleting columns etc. The file to be updated would have a few worksheets in it and every time the worksheets' name and order may be different. Thus, I would like to be able to choose the worksheet I want every time I use the macro. However, I haven't be successful.....

This is the macro. I wanted the mySheet to be variable. Ideally, It can prompt me to choose the worksheet I want within that wbSource..However, I have been getting errors. Anyone know how do I do it?

Thanks in advance!

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim file1 As String
    Dim file2 As String
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim wbLookup As Workbook
    Dim startRange As Range
    Dim mySheet As Worksheet
    Dim col As Range
    Dim Del As Range


    file1 = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select the file to update")
    If Len(Dir(file1)) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    file2 = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select the LOOKUP file")
    If Len(Dir(file2)) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    Set wbLookup = Workbooks.Open(file2)
    Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(file1)
    Set mySheet = wbSource.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name)



    On Error Resume Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Set col = Application.InputBox _
             (Prompt:="Select Column.", _
                    Title:="Where do you want to insert the columns?", Type:=8)

    On Error GoTo 0

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    col.Resize(, 5).EntireColumn.Insert





    On Error Resume Next

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set Del = Application.InputBox _
    (Prompt:="Select Column.", _
     Title:="Which column to delimit?", Type:=8)


     On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True


    Del.EntireColumn.Select '**  ERROR HERE!!

      Selection.TextToColumns _
      Destination:=Del, _
      DataType:=xlDelimited, _
      TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
      ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
      Tab:=False, _
      Semicolon:=False, _
      Comma:=False, _
      Space:=False, _
      Other:=True, _
      OtherChar:="-"

     Del.Offset(0, 2).Delete
     Del.Offset(0, 1).Delete





  On Error Resume Next
    Set startRange = Application.InputBox("Select the first cell for the formula", "Autofill VLOOKUP", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not startRange Is Nothing Then
        Application.Goto startRange
         startRange.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP('[" & wbSource.Name & "]" & mySheet.Name & "'!RC[-1],'[" & wbLookup.Name & "]NON SLL'!C1:C3,3,FALSE)"

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: there is no error in the code you presented... where do you have it exactly and which error number occurs?

Comment: Its the last line.."Set mySheet=......"   I wanted to make the worksheet which is in wbSource to be variable. Is this the way to do it? The error occurs below where I tried to delete a row in this particular worksheet.

Comment: your last line is correct. let's discuss line(s) which causes error(s)...

Comment: hi KazJaw, I did the changes but it gives me an error. Its run time error 9 Subscript out of range

Comment: I deleted some mine incorrect comments, you could also do it with some of yours to keep important part of discussion here...

Comment: ok.i commented below if you have not seen it

Comment: you get that error always if you click `Cancel` in `InputBox`. You could move your `on error goto 0` after last occurrence of `Del` variable in your code.

Comment: hmm.it seems to solve the problem, but now the delimit codes does not delimit.The programme would run through with no error, but it does not do it job of delimiting..

Comment: comment both `On Error...` lines and check again where the error really occurs... I think it's still problem with `Application.InputBox` when pressing cancel. Return error number here and line...

Comment: what do you click when `InputBox` appears? what 'text' is inside `inputbox` after you click but before you press ok? Is there anything unusual in the sheet like merged cell?

Comment: i click on the column which i want to delimit. It works fine when i use wbSource.Sheets(2).The problem is when i want to change the worksheet to be variable.things get wrong.

Comment: in which way you try to do it ('change the worksheet to be variable')?

Comment: Truthfully, I have no idea. I am a beginner in this, so I thought probably doing the ActiveSheet.Name may do the trick,but it haven been successful.

Comment: look, your code is correct in general. I still don't understand this 'change the worksheet to be variable' in relation to `inputbox`. If you call your sub and only click to any cell/column without any changes you still have this `1004 error`? I can't repeat your problem on my machine. So, what you are doing differently?

Comment: hmm,try letting your workbook has maybe 4-5 worksheets with values in them.Using the code, can u randomly choose any worksheet and able to run through the whole macro? The macro is fine if i fixed mySheet as say mabe the 2nd sheet of file 1, but that may not always be the case. So what i really want is able to choose the worksheet and then i will enter the column in that particular worksheet into the inputBox

Comment: but when inputbox appears you can change the sheet by clicking appropriate tab and next you click column... is not ok for you?

Comment: yea i can too, however, it gives me error the moment i ran to the statement Del.EntireColumn.Select. Do u get that at all?

Comment: add this line `Del.Worksheet.Activate` before problem line `Del.EntireColumn.Select` and...??

Comment: and the problem is solved! BUT now the vlookup below returns value N/A for all...

Comment: divide your screen into two parts- excel app and vba editor. Go to your sub and press F8 for step debug. Next press F8 continuously till end and check the logic of your code. you possible need to add some other `Sheets().Activate` methods somewhere.

Comment: argh,i don't have a vba editor in this machine.been working on excel.Alright i will try it out,and maybe get back if anything here?

Comment: press Alt+F11 in Excel to get to your code... this is what I mean...

Comment: been trying.couldn't really pinpoint where to insert anything.

Answer (score 0):

Some continuation from comments and possible explanation of problems...

Your code isn't making any errors. However, there could be some logic mistakes which you should consider. This line of code:

```
Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open(file1)
```

activate the workbook just opened (file1). And next line:

```
Set mySheet = wbSource.Sheets(ActiveSheet.Name)
```

set variable to sheet in just opened workbook (file1) and sheet which is currently active there. 
And general question- is this correct for the logic of further part of your code?

Comment: yea.Basically I want to do a vlookup.and file 1 is the file to be updated with the values lookup from file 2. After that I would like to do a delimit on file 1 too.So file 1 would be the active file

Comment: So @BenjaminAlonsoTan, please add more code to your question, mark the line which in fact raise an error and give error number...